# How to approach grid type problems?

Tags: math, grid, combinatorics

Starting in the top left corner of a 2×2 grid, and only being able to move to the right and down, there are exactly 6 routes to the bottom right corner.

How many such routes are there through a 20×20 grid?

Comment: 2x2 and there are 6 ways being only able to move right and down?

Comment: This sounds like homework, did you do any research on the problem, what is your idea?

Comment: There are exactly 2 routes to the bottom-right corner of a 2x2 grid. You can go down then right, or right then down.

Comment: @Gnqz yes, rrdd, rdrd, rddr, drrd, drdr, ddrr. (r = move right, d = move down). That is a projecteuler question.

Comment: @mch If you do rr, you're now on the 3rd column. But it's only a 2x2 grid, there is no 3rd column.

Comment: How you do double right movement on 2x2 grid o.O you punch the wall or something?

Comment: Counter question: Starting on the bottom right corner of a 2x2 gird and only being able to move right and down, how many routes are there to get to the upper left corner?

Comment: @immibis it would be clearer with the picture from projecteuler. 2x2 means you can go 2 times to the right and 2 times down. 2 is the length, not the number of the points. It is a 3 points x 3 points grid.

Comment: @tobi303 zero? but that's not even relevant.

Comment: This isn't even a programming question, by the way. It's a maths question.

Comment: @mch yes it is a 2*2 grid .Though going by points ,its a 3*3 grid . Can you help me get through this. ?

Comment: Well, when you say a 2x2 grid, I expect 2 rows & 2 columns... So if the YYxYY is the moments, what is the size of the grid then?

Comment: @immibis sorry, sometimes I overdo with sarcasm. My point is: This is not a programming question but a math question. The tags c and c++ are not relevant and moreover I dont think it makes sense to solve a puzzle question by posting it on SO

Comment: @tobi3 its my first question so didnt know about the exact guidelines . Sorry , but can you help me solve this ? would be great of you

Comment: @aakashbharti I could, but why should I? If I did you would not gain anything. Take a piece of paper and a pen, try it for a 3x3 grid, then a 4x4 etc. grid until you get the pattern.

Comment: @tobi3 im good at maths(got an olympiad rank too :p). but i'm like new to programming. can you tell me the approach i need to follow in order to implement the same ?

Comment: the formula to calculate this is somewhere here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination You do not need a program for this, just math.

Comment: Specifically, Project Euler [problem 15](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2x2 case you have 6 possible ways you say. (So I infer from that that you actually move from grid-point to grid-point rather than from cell to cell):
(r,r,d,d), (r,d,r,d), (r,d,d,r), (d,r,d,r), (d,d,r,r), (d,r,r,d).

Note that we always have 2 'd's and 2 'r's. And we always have 4 moves (_ , _, _, _).

Also note, that if you just place the 'r's at the 4 moves, then it is implicitly clear where the 'd's will go, i.e. if you put a 'r' at position 1 and 3 then you will have an 'd' at positions 2 and 4.

Hence you can think of it as: "how many ways are there to distribute 2 'd's to 4 possible positions?". You have to choose 2 elements out of 4.

This is the well known binomial coefficient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) "n choose k". In your case "4 choose 2" (among the 4 choices pick 2) which happens to be 6.

So, now I leave it as an exercise to you: on a 20x20 grid what is your 'n' and what is your 'k'?

The other problem you might run into is how to actually compute the value. But I'm sure you'll figure it out. Just have a close look at the wikipedia page about the binomial coefficient, you might find something useful there.

Comment: .actually its my first post .I've accepted but i cant upvote, reputation issues :p

Comment: @aakashbharti : no problem. Accepting is good enoguh for me ;)